# Disable JSON auto merging data with same ID

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, ajax

I have a simple ajax call to PHP Select request like this :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/renforts/_getIntervenantManager",
    data: {
        IDMission : IDMission,
        IDManager : IDManager
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    global: false,
    success: function(respond) 
    {         
        console.log(respond);
    }
 });
```

and my PHP file look like :

```
$CUIDManager = $_POST['IDManager'];
$IDMission = $_POST['IDMission'];
$pdo_sql_renforts = DB_renforts();
$sql= "SELECT [IDIntervenant], [week], [hours], [year] FROM  ....";  
$requete = $pdo_sql_renforts->prepare($sql);
$requete->execute(array($IDMission, $IDMission,$CUIDManager));
$tab = $requete->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($tab);
```

So far so good here, because I get my respond.

My problem now is that my sql select return something like :

| IDIntervenant | week | hours | year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 16 | 2021 |
| 1 | 23 | 16 | 2021 |
| 1 | 24 | 16 | 2021 |
| 2 | 22 | 16 | 2021 |
| 3 | 25 | 16 | 2021 |

But the JSON respond that I have is merging the line with same ID and create stranges arrays in the first appearance of an ID like this :

```
0 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "1",
    "week": [
        [
            "22",
            "23"
        ],
        "24"
    ],
    "hours": [
        [
            "16",
            "16"
        ],
        "16"
    ],
    "year": [
        [
            "2021",
            "2021"
        ],
        "2021"
    ],
}
1 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "1",
    "week": "23",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
2 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "1",
    "week": "24",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
3 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "2",
    "week": "22",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
4 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "3",
    "week": "25",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
```

And what I want is :

```
0 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "1",
    "week": "22",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
1 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "1",
    "week": "23",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
2 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "1",
    "week": "24",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
3 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "2",
    "week": "22",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
4 : {
    "CUIDIntervenant": "3",
    "week": "25",
    "hours": "16",
    "year": "2021"
}
```

Comment: So, is this the php json that messing things up?

Comment: @vanowm No i don't think so, when i don't set 

` dataType : "json" ` 

in my ajax, I get an string object pretty similar to what I want

Comment: This isn't possible. `fetchAll()` doesn't create nested objects and arrays like that.

Comment: Just look in the devtools for the raw response data of your ajax call

Comment: You can also try `print_r($tab);`  in your php and open it directly in the browser

Comment: @vanowm Ok I try and yes, in my devtools the answer of my ajax is in the format that I want, but in my console.log, it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I know, and my Ajax respond in my devtool is in the format that I want, so it's not from the PHP, but when I console.log my variable respond after, she is modify and not corresponding to what I want :/

Comment: can you provide exact string generated by php?

Comment: `[{"CUIDIntervenant":"1","week":"22","hours":"16","year":"2021"},{"CUIDIntervenant":"1","week":"23","hours":"16","year":"2021"},{"CUIDIntervenant":"1","week":"24","hours":"16","year":"2021"},{"CUIDIntervenant":"2","week":"22","hours":"16","year":"2021"},{"CUIDIntervenant":"3","week":"25","hours":"16","year":"2021"}]
`

Here is the value in my devtool (postman) and in my console when it shows the JSON of the value respond, it add the arrays.

Comment: If you're just doing `console.log(respond)` then it should be the same array as in the JSON. jQuery doesn't modify the response in any way.

Comment: Your ajax is sending `mission`  but PHP is looking for `IDMission`

Comment: @Barmar The answer of the topic has solved my problem so there was a real problem in my log but don't really know why

Comment: @Musa Edited, sorry just a mistake

Answer (score 1):

The json is correct, something is happening inside jquery that messing it up. Try receive it as text and convert it manually:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/renforts/_getIntervenantManager",
  data: {
    mission: IDMission,
    IDManager: IDManager
  },
  dataType: 'text',
  global: false,
  success: function(respond) {
    console.log("original response");
    console.log(respond);
    console.log("JSON");
    console.log(JSON.parse(respond));
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, it solve my problem, do you know what I can change to solve that Jquery problem?

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` just makes it call `JSON.parse()` automatically. There should be no difference from what you're doing here.